# talend how to update the stage table after data operation

Tags: sql-server, talend

I am using Talend for the first time and had a question - i am loading data to a staging table and then running an ETL job from the staging to the target database table.

The staging table has got a status column with a error column  to indicate the status of database operation (DONE or FAIL) and what was the error if the record FAILED (for log generation). Need to update this via a Stored procedure

After my database operation is done - how can i can access the staging table primary key? This field is not mapped from the stage to actual table
[image]

Comment: cant you create another output row group from tmap so that your tmap has two outputs - one for inserting and other for other purpose

Comment: What do you want to do with the PK ? you want to use stg_ga_event_id in your insertRow ? or do you want to get the event based on yourevent_id ? re format your question please.